# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PaypalAdaptive. It sends ipn_notification properly. ipnNotification action method is as following -

```
def ipn_notification
    ipn = PaypalAdaptive::IpnNotification.new
    ipn.send_back(request.raw_post.to_json)

    print "=====================request.raw_post#{request.raw_post}=============="

    if ipn.verified?
        PaymentMailer.notify_unknown(request.raw_post).deliver
    else
        logger.info "IT DIDNT WORK"
    end
    render :nothing => true
end
```

but it's returning error

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails
```

Any help for this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:ipn_notification]
```

For people reading to quickly and distribute -1 (skipping an important part: it's not a POST call from the client...):

- yes it skips a security BUT... Read after...
- yes, it's the only way for external website POST requests
- yes it's safe: you obviously check params and keys when receiving a call from Paypal or alike.

Comment: Answers are better when explained, too ;)

Comment: It is not the very short answer that made me -1 it. It is the missing explanation of the security implications that come with an implementation like yours. You basically bypass the CSRF protection .. which is a bad thing in combination with payment ;)

Comment: @matthiaskrull is there any alternative when receiving post from tierce services? I dont think so. Since the response is then checked using shared auth keys, it's not an issue.

Comment: I don't see any. But that is not the point I wanted to make. Maybe it is just me but I think it is worth mentioning what a line of code really does if it changes security relevant behavior.

Comment: @matthiaskrull when there is no alternative and the answer is good, your remark makes a great comment. I leave you happy with blaming power

Comment: @apneadiving This answer is opening very basic and big security hole in the authentication system. The simplest and easy way to solve this is by settings the headers in the request so the authentication doesnot break. Check the other answer to know more.

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal you are completely wrong when it concerns external calls like the one the OP is talking about.

Comment: How do you get paypal to send the correct headers? You don't.

Answer (score 15):

The correct solution for this problem without compromising security

In your ajax request send the csrf token value as header.

```
var csrfToken = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
  }
});
```

Comment: @Magnum better approach? Maybe, alas, it does not answer the question – apneadiving 1 hour ago

Comment: That is why I said it is 'better approach' not 'answer'

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line in your application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And try.